# C: Declaring function with a parameter changes its behavior...?

Tags: c, parameters, fork, execve

I'm playing around with signals, fork, and execve, and I've written a toy program that uses `fork()` to create a child process that calls another toy program. Then the parent sets an alarm to kill the function after a certain number of seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <signal.h>

pid_t childPid;

pid_t Fork()
{
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        printf("Error:\n");
    return pid;
}

void killhandler(int sig)
/*This will be called when we receive a SIGALRM*/
{
    int status;
    printf("\nAssassin: *ksh* Received order to kill process: %d\n", (int)childPid);
    if (!(status = kill(childPid, SIGKILL))) {
        printf("Assassin: Clean and discreet. My work here is done. *ksh*\n");
    } else {
        printf("Assassin: He got away!\n");
    }
}

void forkyMcFork()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    /*Generate information for new program*/
    char* argv[] = {"problem5", "Hello"};
    char* envp[] = {"PANTS=JEANS"};
    char* func = "problem5";

    /* Create child process, child process calls executable "problem5" */
    if ((pid = Fork()) == 0) {
        printf("Child: I am a child! Woohoo!\n");
        if (execve(func, argv, envp) < 0)
            printf("Child: error, %s not found\n", func);
        while(1);
    }
    else {
        /* Parent process sets alarm, then prints a message depending on exit status*/
        childPid = pid;
        alarm(3);
        printf("Parent: I am the parent!\n");
        waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("Parent: Oh no, what happened to my baby!!!\n");
            exit(0);
        } else {
            printf("Parent: Child came home without any problems.\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGALRM, killhandler);
    forkyMcFork();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the weird part: if I declare the function `forkyMcFork()` as taking no parameters, and then set the argument for `alarm()` manually, then it works just as I would expect: the child process starts `problem5`, which asks for some input from the user, and then after 3 seconds, `killhandler` runs, finds the child process and kills it:

```
$ ./forkfun
Parent: I am the parent!
Child: I am a child! Woohoo!
Please type name. If finished press enter: Haha
Please type name. If finished press enter: 
Assassin: *ksh* Received order to kill process: 42409
Assassin: Clean and discreet. My work here is done. *ksh*
Parent: Oh no, what happened to my baby!!!
$
```

However, if I declare instead `forkyMcFork(int secs)` and then use `alarm(secs)`, the external program that should be called by the `execve()` statement in the child program is not found. The alarm runs as expected, so after some number of seconds the child process gets axed.

Here's the non-working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <signal.h>

pid_t childPid;

pid_t Fork()
{
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        printf("Error:\n");
    return pid;
}

void killhandler(int sig)
/*This will be called when we receive a SIGALRM*/
{
    int status;
    printf("\nAssassin: *ksh* Received order to kill process: %d\n", (int)childPid);
    if (!(status = kill(childPid, SIGKILL))) {
        printf("Assassin: Clean and discreet. My work here is done. *ksh*\n");
    } else {
        printf("Assassin: He got away!\n");
    }
}

void forkyMcFork(int secs)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    /*Generate information for new program*/
    char* argv[] = {"problem5", "Hello"};
    char* envp[] = {"PANTS=JEANS"};
    char* func = "problem5";

    /* Create child process, child process calls executable "problem5" */
    if ((pid = Fork()) == 0) {
        printf("Child: I am a child! Woohoo!\n");
        if (execve(func, argv, envp) < 0)
            printf("Child: error, %s not found\n", func);
        while(1);
    }
    else {
        /* Parent process sets alarm, then prints a message depending on exit status*/
        childPid = pid;
        alarm(secs);
        printf("Parent: I am the parent!\n");
        waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("Parent: Oh no, what happened to my baby!!!\n");
            exit(0);
        } else {
            printf("Parent: Child came home without any problems.\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGALRM, killhandler);
    forkyMcFork(5);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output of that:

```
$ ./forkfun 
Parent: I am the parent!
Child: I am a child! Woohoo!
Child: error, problem5 not found

Assassin: *ksh* Received order to kill process: 42400
Assassin: Clean and discreet. My work here is done. *ksh*
Parent: Oh no, what happened to my baby!!!
$
```

So to be clear, the only code difference here is whether `forkyMcFork` is declared as taking `void`, in which case it works, or as taking `int secs`, in which case it doesn't. What's going on?

Comment: When you get the error from `execve`, print the value of `errno` too, or even better use [`strerror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) to get a printable text of the error code.

Comment: Also please show the program that _fails_ instead of the program that succeeds.

Comment: Add a null argument onto the end of your argv and envp variables in ForkyMcFork().  You may just be getting lucky either version works.

Comment: @Duck that's a good enough guess that I'd suggest posting it as an answer :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I pasted that in as well; thanks.

Comment: @Duck thanks! That did fix it. I forgot that argv and envp had to be null-terminated. I'm now curious as to why it worked without it.

Comment: Empty parentheses in a C function declaration don't mean it has no parameters; it means it has an unspecified but fixed number and type(s) of parameters. It's an old-style declaration from before prototypes were added to the language, and it's an obsolescent feature. Rather than `void forkyMcFork()`, write `void forkyMcFork(void)`. (C++ is different; in C++ empty parentheses do mean "no parameters", and old-style declarations are illegal.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an answer in Duck comment - so just to summarize:

> int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[],
>                     char *const envp[]);
>
> *argv* is an array of argument strings passed to the new program.  *envp*
>   is an
>          array of strings, conventionally of the form key=value, which are passed as
>          environment to the new program.  Both argv and envp must be terminated by a
>          null pointer.

So I suggest to add NULL also for terminating **envp**.